# Micro Services With Docker Compose: Same Container, Multiple Projects

Tags: docker, docker-compose, microservices

Along with a few others, I am having issues using a micro services architecture of applications and employing `docker-compose` the way I want to.

Summary:
I have `X` micro service projects (lets call these `project A`, `project B` and `project C`. Each micro service depends on the same containers (lets call these `dependency D` and `dependency E`.

The Problem:
Ideally, project `A`, `B` and `C` would **ALL** have both dependencies (`D` & `E`) in their docker-compose.yml files; however, this becomes an issue as docker compose sees these as *duplicate* containers when in reality, I would like to reuse them. Here is an error message that is commonly seen:

> ERROR: for A Cannot create container for service A: b'Conflict. The
>   container name "/A" is already in use by container "sha". You have to
>   remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.'

From what I have seen, [people are recommending that you define the container in one project and reference it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45915624/4930850) using `networks` and external links. Although this works, it introduces a dependency on a different docker-compose yml file (the file that defines the dependency!).

Another approach that I've read argues for isolation of containers in their docker compose files and then referencing multiple files when you want to build. Again, although this works, its certainly not as stunningly convenient as docker typically is to work with. If I am unable to work out a solution, I will go with this approach.

Have other people in the non-mono repo world (specifically with micro services) had any success with a different approach?

---

I've been ask to clarify with some examples:

Here is what 2 different compose yml files look like for `project A` and `project B`:

Project A:

```
version: '2'
services:
  dependencyD:
    image: dependencyD:latest
    container_name: dependencyD

  dependencyE:
    image: dependencyE:latest
    container_name: dependencyE

  projectA:
    image: projectA:latest
    container_name: projectA
    depends_on:
      - dependencyD
      - dependencyE
```

Project B:

```
version: '2'
services:
  dependencyD:
    image: dependencyD:latest
    container_name: dependencyD

  dependencyE:
    image: dependencyE:latest
    container_name: dependencyE

  projectB:
    image: projectB:latest
    container_name: projectB
    depends_on:
      - dependencyD
      - dependencyE
```

Comment: Can you post a sample docker-compose file?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is

Comment: First, you cannot have two containers with the same name in one host (specified by container_name in your docker run or in compose file). You can use multiple compose files, but docker won't start the containers. Besides, you are confusing by using same name for your project and dependencies. Is project A and dependency A are same thing or different? As reco suggested, can you post some the compose file you are using?

Comment: I've added some examples. My apologies for the potentially confusing description

Answer (score 3):

There is a feature called [external links](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external_links). From the docs:

> Link to containers started outside this docker-compose.yml or even outside of Compose, especially for containers that provide shared or common services.

Having multiple `docker-compose.yml` files is also common to organize containers into meaningful groups. Maybe your scenario can use multiple YAML files and the *external links*.

Comment: This is what I've essentially gathered and mentioned in both of my potential approaches.

Comment: Other than exposing ports and juggling external IP addresses around, I don't see a way to conveniently connect the containers. I think this is the limit of docker-compose and the reason why people then switch to something more powerful like Kubernetes.